# Rejection sampling confusion

Tags: sampling, sample

I have a confusion about the "intuitive explanation" of rejection sampling given at this link on (apologies, I know it's not always a good source) [Rejection Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). The text in the introduction reads as follows (emphasis and additions mine)

> Rejection sampling works as follows:
>
> 1. Sample point on x-axis from proposal distribution **p(x)**.
> 2. Draw vertical line at this x-position, up to the **maximum** y-value of the proposal distribution, **p(x)**.
> 3. Sample uniformly along this line **$\alpha$** from 0 to the **maximum** of the probability density function **p(x)**. If sampled value is greater than the value of the desired distribution at this vertical line **f(x)**, reject the x-value and return to step 1; else the x-value is a sample from the desired distribution.

My confusion is in the use of the word "maximum." The mathematical formulation of the rejection criterion is based upon comparing the uniform random variable $\alpha$ as follows:

1. Draw $\alpha \sim U(0, M p(x))$ where $M$ is the constant ensuring $Mp(x) > f(x)$ envelopes the desired distribution.
2. If $\alpha > f(x)$ reject.

However, the text written above seems to suggest drawing $\alpha \sim U(0, \textrm{max}(p(x))$ which greatly increases the spread of the samples, since we would now include values of $\alpha > p(x)$.

**Is the article incorrect, or is it assuming that the proposal distribution is uniform? Or have I misinterpreted the text and the use of the word "maximum?"**

Related to this, the application of my question is to the following:

I want to use rejection sampling to improve the sampling of a function. Right now I am generating samples from a proposal, p(x), with a mechanism that approximates the desired distribution, f(x), but in such a way that *I don't actually know p(x)*.

**Is there a sampling method that allows me to accept or reject these samples according to their value of f(x) without knowing the exact value of p(x) for each sample x?**

Comment: The whole idea of rejection sampling is to compare your function f, which can be arbitrarily hard to deal with, with a known and relatively simple function p. If your p is hard to evaluate than you have a chosen a bad p. The p function can be whatever, but it should always be greater than f, so you can imagine for ex. choosing a normal distribution multiplied by a factor of 2 for p.

Comment: The way it is written in that section of the wikipedia article is confusing; it seems like an attempt to make it more intuitive. Your understanding of it is correct. The wikipedia article explains it better in the section after that.

Comment: Ok, great, so the sample that is taken along their "vertical line" goes up to the proposal distribution at the point $x$, being $p(x)$ and _not_ up to the maximum of the distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation is doubly confusing in that (1) the "maximum" is meant as $p(x)$ rather than as $\max_x p(x)$. And (2) this maximum should be $Mp(x)$ where $M$ is an upper bound on $f(x)/p(x)$ over all $x$'s. Generating a pair $(x,\alpha)$ this way produces a Uniform generation over the sub-graph of the function $Mp(\cdot)$. In the event the pair $(x,\alpha)$  also belongs to the sub-graph of the function $f(\cdot)$, it is then a Uniform generation over this sub-graph. Therefore, the marginal density of the accepted $x$ is $f(x)$, which validates the algorithm. (This is also the principle behind slice sampling.)

Here is an illustration taken [from our book](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa) (pp.53-54):

> To simulate beta $\mathcal{B}e(\alpha, \beta)$ random variables, we
> can, however, construct a toy algorithm based on the Accept--Reject
> method, using as the instrumental distribution the uniform ${\cal
>   U}_{[0,1]}$ distribution when both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are larger
> than $1$. (The generic `rbeta` function does not impose this restriction.)
>
> The upper bound $M$ is then the maximum of the beta density, obtained
> for instance by `optimize` (or its alias
> `optimise`):

```
 optimize(f=function(x){dbeta(x,2.7,6.3)},
         interval=c(0,1),max=T)$objective
 [1] 2.669744
```

> Since the candidate density $g$ is equal to one, the proposed value
> $Y$is accepted if $M \times U < f(Y)$, that is, if $M \times U$ is
> under the beta density $f$ at that realization. Note that generating
> $U \sim {\mathcal U}_{[0,1]}$ and multiplying $U$ by $M$ is equivalent to
> generating $U \sim {\mathcal U}_{[0,M]}$. For $\alpha = 2.7$ and
> $\beta = 6.3$, an alternative \R implementation of the Accept--Reject
> algorithm is

```
   Nsim=2500
   a=2.7;b=6.3
   M=2.67
   u=runif(Nsim,max=M)    #uniform over (0,M)
   y=runif(Nsim)          #generation from g
   x=y[u<dbeta(y,a,b)]    #accepted subsample
```

> and the left panel in the Figure below shows the results of generating
> $2500$ pairs $(Y,U)$ from ${\mathcal U}_{[0,1]}\times{\mathcal
>   U}_{[0,M]}$. The black dots $(Y,Ug(Y))$ that fall under the density
> $f$ are those for which we accept $X=Y$, and we reject the grey dots
> $(Y,Ug(Y))$ that fall outside. It is again clear from this graphical
> representation that the black dots are uniformly distributed over the
> area under the density $f$. Since the probability of acceptance of a
> given simulation is  $1/M$, with $M=2.67$ we accept approximately
> $1/2.67 = 37\%$ of the values.

[image]

> Consider instead simulating $Y \sim \mathcal{B}e(2, 6)$ as a proposal distribution.
> This choice of $g$ is acceptable since

```
 optimize(f=function(x){dbeta(x,2.7,6.3)/dbeta(x,2,6)},
 max=T,interval=c(0,1))$objective
 [1] 1.671808
```

> This modification of the proposal thus leads to a smaller value of $M$ and a correspondingly higher acceptance rate of $58\%$ than with the uniform proposal.
> The right panel of the Figure shows the outcome of the corresponding Accept--Reject algorithm and illustrates the gain in efficiency brought by simulating points in a smaller set.

---

When considering the second part of the question,given that the choice of $p(\cdot)$ is open, among those densities bounding $f(\cdot)$, computing $p(x)$ is not a primary issue when using Accept-Reject algorithms.

> Is there a sampling method that allows me to accept or reject these
> samples according to their value of f(x) without knowing the exact
> value of p(x) for each sample x?

What matters is the ability to compute the ratio $f(x)/Mp(x)$ for any given $x$. This means that

1. both densities $f$ and $p$ only need be known up to a normalising constant
2. $p$ can be chosen towards eliminating the computation of intractable parts of $f$. That is, if $f(\cdot)=f_1(\cdot)f_2(\cdot)$ where $f_2(x)$ cannot be computed, choosing $p(\cdot)=p_1(\cdot)f_2(\cdot)$ eliminates the need to compute $f_2(x)$, providing $p(\cdot)$ can be simulated, i.e., is a generative model.
3. if $f(x)$ can be written as$$f(x)=\int_\mathfrak Z \tilde f(x,z)\text dz$$ where the integral is intractable and $\tilde f(x,z)$ can be computed, using a proposal density $\tilde p(x,z)$ such that $\tilde f(x,z)/\tilde p(x,z)$ is bounded is sufficient for simulating $f$ even though $f(x)$ cannot be computed.